# room android database is locked

Tags: android, database, android-room

I had been getting " android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException" exception from production。
An exception occurred during error analysis.my project database is room. Multi-process is not used in the project.The database room has encapsulated transaction operations. I don’t know why the database is locked. Hope to get your help，thanks!

```
this is exception

Process Name: &#39;com.geek.jk.weather&#39;
Thread Name: &#39;kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker#DefaultDispatcher-worker-2&#39;
Back traces starts.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:553)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:323)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.beginTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:298)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:505)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:416)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:1)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:4)
    at com.xiaoniu.unitionadbase.collie.dao.EventTrackDao_Impl$3.call(EventTrackDao_Impl.java:2)
    at com.xiaoniu.unitionadbase.collie.dao.EventTrackDao_Impl$3.call(EventTrackDao_Impl.java:1)
    at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:2)
    at Rza.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:3)
    at WIa.run(DispatchedTask.kt:18)
    at androidx.room.TransactionExecutor$1.run(TransactionExecutor.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Back traces ends.
```

database

```
@Database(entities = [CommonTrack::class, EventTrack::class], version = 1)
abstract class TrackDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun CommonTrackDao(): CommonTrackDao
abstract fun EventTrackDao(): EventTrackDao

companion object {

    private var instance: TrackDatabase? = null


    fun getInstance(context: Context): TrackDatabase {
        return instance ?: instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
        
    }

    fun buildDatabase(context: Context): TrackDatabase {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    TrackDatabase::class.java,
                    "event_track.db"
            ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()

        }
        return instance as TrackDatabase
    }
}
```

}

Database usage

```
@Dao
abstract class EventTrackDao {

@Query("select * from event_table limit 50 ")
abstract suspend fun getEventTack():List<EventTrack>

@Query("select count(*) from event_table")
abstract suspend fun getEventCounts():Int

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
abstract suspend fun insertEventTrack(events: List<EventTrack>):List<Long>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
abstract suspend fun insertEventTrack(event:EventTrack):Long


@Delete
abstract suspend  fun removeEvent(events: List<EventTrack>)
```

}

```
val call=  TrackDatabase.getInstance(context).EventTrackDao().insertEventTrack(eventslist)

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        runCatching {
                            val 
                            list=TrackDatabase.getInstance(context).EventTrackDao().getEventCounts()

                        }.onFailure {t ->
                            
                       }
                    }
```

EventTrackDao_Impl

```
public final class EventTrackDao_Impl extends EventTrackDao {
private final RoomDatabase __db;

private final EntityInsertionAdapter<EventTrack> __insertionAdapterOfEventTrack;

private final EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter<EventTrack> __deletionAdapterOfEventTrack;

public EventTrackDao_Impl(RoomDatabase __db) {
  this.__db = __db;
  this.__insertionAdapterOfEventTrack = new EntityInsertionAdapter<EventTrack>(__db) {
  @Override
  public String createQuery() {
    return "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO `event_table` (`event_param`,`ts`) VALUES (?,?)";
  }

  @Override
  public void bind(SupportSQLiteStatement stmt, EventTrack value) {
    if (value.getParam() == null) {
      stmt.bindNull(1);
    } else {
      stmt.bindString(1, value.getParam());
    }
    stmt.bindLong(2, value.getTs());
  }
};
this.__deletionAdapterOfEventTrack = new EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter<EventTrack>(__db) {
  @Override
  public String createQuery() {
    return "DELETE FROM `event_table` WHERE `event_param` = ?";
  }

  @Override
  public void bind(SupportSQLiteStatement stmt, EventTrack value) {
    if (value.getParam() == null) {
      stmt.bindNull(1);
    } else {
      stmt.bindString(1, value.getParam());
    }
  }
};
```

}
}

Answer (score 2):

Your database class still allow multithread modify due to lock database. Modify class database with `Volatile` and `synchronized` like this:

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Word::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class WordRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

   abstract fun wordDao(): WordDao

   companion object {
        // Singleton prevents multiple instances of database opening at the
        // same time. 
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): WordRoomDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        WordRoomDatabase::class.java, 
                        "word_database"
                    ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
   }
}
```

You must call insert action in coroutine scope with IO context.

Comment: thanks，Modify class database add  Volatile  and synchronized , the problem still exists

Comment: @hanchenke I updated answer. The reason you call insert not in coroutines scope

Comment: my project  call  insert in coroutines scope. Here is just to show the insert code

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing the synchronized block, and adding the following code `.enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()` to the builder

It should become `Room.databaseBuilder( context.applicationContext, WordRoomDatabase::class.java,  "word_database" ).enableMultiInstanceInvalidation().build()`

Answer (score 0):

Add `enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()` and `@Volatile` when you build your database.

Example:

```
private fun buildMyDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase =
            Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, BuildConfig.DB_NAME)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .setJournalMode(JournalMode.AUTOMATIC)
                .enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
                .build()
}
```